# Jquery: Syntax error, unrecognized expression :nth-child()

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I've used someone else's answer to get this.

Jquery:

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var columnName = $(this).attr('name');
    $('td:nth-child(' + columnName + '),th:nth-child(' + columnName + ')').hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var columnName = $(this).attr('name');
    $('td:nth-child(' + columnName + '),th:nth-child(' + columnName + ')').toggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1" checked="checked"/>
```

It works when I put values in the :nth-child(1) but not when I include the variable. Am I doing it wrong or am I using the wrong Jquery library.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: Can you post your HTML code too?

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem in a fiddle? It sounds like you have checkboxes whose name attribute is **not** a number

Comment: I don't see a problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/B2Wb4/

Comment: It looks like you're trying to react on some element whose name is empty

Comment: @billyonecan http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/NLdtv/

Comment: @Antony That's what I dont understand, I put it in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/NLdtv/

Comment: @msbodetti That's because you forgot to load jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/NLdtv/1/

Comment: @Antony Ah thanks but I did include it into my php header file <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> Is it the wrong one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you have one or more `<input type="checkbox" />` where the `name` attribute is **not** a number, or is not present.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="string" />
```

When using your code, this outputs the error you described:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child
```

#### [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XXBXx/1/)

A workaround would be to check that `columnName` is a valid number:

```
var columnName = $(this).prop('name') || '0';

if (columnName.match(/^[1-9]\d*$/)) {
  // columnName must start with a number between 1 to 9
  // and can be proceeded by zero or more numbers only
}
```

Also, it would be a better idea to assign a `class` to the checkboxes which are used to `show/hide` the corresponding `td/th's`.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="showHide" name="1" />
```

That way, you're only selecting/looping over the elements you want, and not every checkbox on the page.

```
$('input.showHide').click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: I'm not using strings, only numbers http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/NLdtv/ It's not working in the fiddle..

Comment: @msbodetti it works fine in the fiddle. You didn't include jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/NLdtv/2/

Comment: Ah thanks but I did include it into my php header file   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Is it the wrong one?

Comment: No, it's not the wrong one. You just didn't include it in the fiddle, which is why it didn't work.

Comment: Ok thanks, but it's not working in my files. And I'm using the same format in the fiddle. Should I include a different Jquery library?

Comment: I'm going to have to use it without the variable, it's just picking it up as a string and not a number.