# JQuery: How to trigger certain events depending on what is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a row of images displayed and I want to display a different list item when each picture is clicked. Here's a demo of what I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/OneCodeMan/3975prLy/1/

```
$("img:nth-child(1)").on('click', function() {
  $("#listitem1").text(lines[0]);
});

$("img:nth-child(2)").on('click', function() {
   $("#listitem2").text(lines[1]);
});
```

But that's for eight images.. so this is too much code to do all that.
I tried making a for loop too.

```
for(var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        $('img.nth-child(' + parseInt(i+1) +')').on('click', function() {
            $("#listitem"+ i+1).text(lines[i]);
        })
    }
```

But I got this error:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: img.nth-child(1)

How do I fix this?

Comment: looks like this is simply a typo - you need `:nth-child()`, not `.nth-child()`

Comment: I think this topic might be helpful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981342/jquery-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-nth-child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it with **[.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)**, and **[.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** so:

```
$("#shots img").on('click', function() {
  var idx=$(this).index();
  $("#alcoholpoem li").eq(idx).text(lines[idx]);
});
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
var lines = ['Eight shots later,',
  'I still remember your name.',
  'I never drank alcohol,',
  'For the taste',
  'This is text',
  'This is text',
  'This is text',
  'This is text'
];

$("#shots img").on('click', function() {
  var idx = $(this).index();
  $("#alcoholpoem li").eq(idx).text(lines[idx]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shots">

  <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzUxWDY0MA==/z/PRoAAMXQNbxRfYfj/$T2eC16VHJH!FFmOoS6i!BRfYfi6Vl!~~60_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F" width=100 height=100>
  <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzUxWDY0MA==/z/PRoAAMXQNbxRfYfj/$T2eC16VHJH!FFmOoS6i!BRfYfi6Vl!~~60_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F" width=100 height=100>
  <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzUxWDY0MA==/z/PRoAAMXQNbxRfYfj/$T2eC16VHJH!FFmOoS6i!BRfYfi6Vl!~~60_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F" width=100 height=100>
  <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzUxWDY0MA==/z/PRoAAMXQNbxRfYfj/$T2eC16VHJH!FFmOoS6i!BRfYfi6Vl!~~60_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F" width=100 height=100>
  <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzUxWDY0MA==/z/PRoAAMXQNbxRfYfj/$T2eC16VHJH!FFmOoS6i!BRfYfi6Vl!~~60_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F" width=100 height=100>
  <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzUxWDY0MA==/z/PRoAAMXQNbxRfYfj/$T2eC16VHJH!FFmOoS6i!BRfYfi6Vl!~~60_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F" width=100 height=100>
  <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzUxWDY0MA==/z/PRoAAMXQNbxRfYfj/$T2eC16VHJH!FFmOoS6i!BRfYfi6Vl!~~60_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F" width=100 height=100>
  <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzUxWDY0MA==/z/PRoAAMXQNbxRfYfj/$T2eC16VHJH!FFmOoS6i!BRfYfi6Vl!~~60_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F" width=100 height=100>

</div>

<ul id="alcoholpoem">
  <li id="listitem1"></li>
  <li id="listitem2"></li>
  <li id="listitem3"></li>
  <li id="listitem4"></li>
  <li id="listitem5"></li>
  <li id="listitem6"></li>
  <li id="listitem7"></li>
  <li id="listitem8"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.index()`

```
$("img").on("click", function() {
  $("#listitem1").text(lines[$(this).index()]);
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3975prLy/3/

Comment: Thanks. How would I put it on different list tags though? I tried making a for loop with your code and replacing #listitem1 with listitem"+parseInt(i+1), doesn't work?

Comment: Alternatively, using attribute ends with selector https://jsfiddle.net/3975prLy/7/. Though simplest approach would be to begin numbers at `id` of `li` elements at `0` instead of `1`, corresponding to index of `img` element