# JQUERY: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child

Tags: jquery, wordpress

My website is having issue with JQUERY so sliders and some functionalities are not working.

**Error - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child**

URL - http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/

Is there any way to resolve this issue ? I'm using Wordpress and BigBang WP Template.[image]

Comment: can you provide your code in addition? we can't guess what is the actual problem here :-)

Comment: I haven't added any custom codes, This issue is happened after updating wordpress to new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not completed **a tag** properly.

Your code is following.

```
<h3>2016 Media Partners</h3>
<ul class='grid row6 clients'>
<li>
 <a href="https://squareup.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/7.png" alt="7" width="225" height="140" /> </a><a href="http://ieee.org/WOMEN" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/3.png" alt="3" width="225" height="140" /></a><a title="MCE" href="http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/mce_ems_services.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/MCE.jpg" alt="MCE" width="196" height="69" /></a><a title="NCWIT" href="http://www.ncwit.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/ncwit.png" alt="ncwit" width="133" height="120" data-wp-pid="3426" /></a><a href="http://www.lightreading.com/women-in-comms.asp" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/WiC-Member-Badge-1.png" alt="WiC Member Badge-1" width="182" height="112" /></a><a href="http://codechix.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/codechix-logo-square-black.png" alt="codechix-logo-square-black" width="119" height="119" /></a><a href="http://www.MillionWomenMentors.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/GiT_logo_rgb_square_hr.png" alt="GiT_logo_rgb_square_hr" width="118" height="118" /> </a><a href="http://www.gridalternatives.org/" target="_blank"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5465" src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Horizontal-GRID-logo.png" alt="Horizontal-GRID-logo" width="1674" height="635" data-wp-pid="5465" /></a> <a href="http://www.womenintechcampaign.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/WIT-Logo.png" alt="WIT Logo" width="207" height="52" /></a><a href="http://www.MillionWomenMentors.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/MWM-LOGO.png" alt="MWM LOGO" width="208" height="110" /></a> <a href="http://www.ConvoForGood.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/C4G_250H.png" alt="C4G" width="208" height="110" /></a> <a href="http://sheplusplus.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/she-_logo.png" alt="she++_logo" width="117" height="100" /></a> <a href="http://www.oceanicengineering.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Oceanic.jpg" alt="Oceanic" width="168" height="79" /></a> <a href="http://sites.ieee.org/ttm/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/TTM_250H.jpg" alt="TTM_250H" width="250" height="188" /> </a><a href="http://ieee-wie-scv.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IEEE-SCV.jpg" alt="IEEE SCV" width="200" height="90" /> </a><a href="http://ieee-region6.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IEEE-R6.jpg" alt="IEEE R6" width="300" height="80" /> </a><a href="https://women.acm.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/acmw_europe_250H.jpg" alt="acmw_europe_250H" width="250" height="154" />
</li>
</ul></a></p>
```

Please change it to:

```
<h3>2016 Media Partners</h3>
<ul class='grid row6 clients'>
<li>
 <a href="https://squareup.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/7.png" alt="7" width="225" height="140" /> </a><a href="http://ieee.org/WOMEN" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/3.png" alt="3" width="225" height="140" /></a><a title="MCE" href="http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/mce_ems_services.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/MCE.jpg" alt="MCE" width="196" height="69" /></a><a title="NCWIT" href="http://www.ncwit.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/ncwit.png" alt="ncwit" width="133" height="120" data-wp-pid="3426" /></a><a href="http://www.lightreading.com/women-in-comms.asp" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/WiC-Member-Badge-1.png" alt="WiC Member Badge-1" width="182" height="112" /></a><a href="http://codechix.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/codechix-logo-square-black.png" alt="codechix-logo-square-black" width="119" height="119" /></a><a href="http://www.MillionWomenMentors.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/GiT_logo_rgb_square_hr.png" alt="GiT_logo_rgb_square_hr" width="118" height="118" /> </a><a href="http://www.gridalternatives.org/" target="_blank"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5465" src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Horizontal-GRID-logo.png" alt="Horizontal-GRID-logo" width="1674" height="635" data-wp-pid="5465" /></a> <a href="http://www.womenintechcampaign.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/WIT-Logo.png" alt="WIT Logo" width="207" height="52" /></a><a href="http://www.MillionWomenMentors.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/MWM-LOGO.png" alt="MWM LOGO" width="208" height="110" /></a> <a href="http://www.ConvoForGood.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/C4G_250H.png" alt="C4G" width="208" height="110" /></a> <a href="http://sheplusplus.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/she-_logo.png" alt="she++_logo" width="117" height="100" /></a> <a href="http://www.oceanicengineering.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Oceanic.jpg" alt="Oceanic" width="168" height="79" /></a> <a href="http://sites.ieee.org/ttm/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/TTM_250H.jpg" alt="TTM_250H" width="250" height="188" /> </a><a href="http://ieee-wie-scv.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IEEE-SCV.jpg" alt="IEEE SCV" width="200" height="90" /> </a><a href="http://ieee-region6.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IEEE-R6.jpg" alt="IEEE R6" width="300" height="80" /> </a><a href="https://women.acm.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ieee-wie-ilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/acmw_europe_250H.jpg" alt="acmw_europe_250H" width="250" height="154" /></a>
</li>
</ul></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error usually occurs when the `nth-child` operation is provided with non-number parameter. See this question as a reference: [Jquery: Syntax error, unrecognized expression :nth-child()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981342/jquery-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-nth-child)